# Can I make the EmberJS link-to helper use the touchStart event instead of click?

Tags: cordova, ember.js, touchstart

The title pretty much sums up my question. The reason is, I'm building an Ember app in PhoneGap, and there is a very slight delay on each click event. The touchStart event is more recommended. I would prefer to be able to define a separate helper (touch-to) for this if possible, or add a class to the link that will use the touch event instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the event that LinkView uses (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.LinkView.html#property_eventName):

```
Ember.LinkView.reopen({
    eventName: 'touchStart'
});
```

Comment: Seems to work! Clicking on nav items is instant now, before it had about a 300ms delay.